# positioning transparent images as background in the title slide

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, backgrounds

How can I put five transparent images in different positions of the background in the title slide of a beamer presentation?

Comment: Try `\AddToShipoutPictureBG`. There is also a beamer template that let you control the background.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the images to the `background canvas` template and arrange them e.g. with tikz:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

{
  \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[opacity=0.3]
      \node at (0,0) {\includegraphics{example-image-duck}};
      \node at (4,4) {\includegraphics{example-image-duck}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame} 
}   
  
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}  
\end{document}
```